# Plotting multiple lines onto one graph from for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a for loop running through my data to find dips in my data set. This gives me five different graphs. I need to superimpose these five graphs onto each other with different colors. Yes, it will ve very messy.

I've done this before but not while it's in a four loop so I'm not sure how to go about it. Here is my data

```
# data
data = np.loadtxt('student_021.txt') # loading light curve data file 
time_x = data[:,0] # taking the first column of data
lum_y = data[:,1] # second column

mean = lum_y.mean() # mean value of the light curve
std = lum_y.std() # standard deviation of the light curve

light_dip = [] # initalize empty array for areas where the light curve dips 
end = None # cut off the values here where the data goes to normal

# for loop to go through the data and find where the light dips are 
for i, x in enumerate(lum_y): #enumerate to assign positional values so I can identify and separate them 
    if x < mean - (std *4): # if the iterator is less than the mean - an arbitrarily chosen 4stds 
        if not light_dip: # is it an outlier or not?
            light_dip.append(i) # if it is, let me know and append the data
            end = i
        else:
            if i > end + 250: # find the end of the light dip
                end = light_dip.append(i)
                end = i
                
print(light_dip)
```

```
# plotting the primary chart
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlabel('Time(s)')
ax.set_ylabel('Brightnes')
ax.plot(time_x,lum_y)
plt.title('Original Graph')
```

```
for dip in light_dip: # sort through and print out the five different light dips
    i = max(dip - 50, 0) # left limit
    j = dip + 150 # right limit

    factor_x = time_x[i:j]
    factor_y = lum_y[i:j]
    
    # plotting
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Brightnes')
    #ax.plot(time_x,lum_y)
    ax.plot(factor_x, factor_y)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you present the code and toy data, you may get a faster answer.

Comment: You call `fig = plt.figure()` and `ax = ...` inside the loop. What do you think that will do?